# CloseableHttpClient: connection hangs forever

Tags: httpclient

I have a problem with a connection managed by CloseableHttpClient.
A Spring service manages ny connection:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
...
    private CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient;

    public String setPayment() {
...
        try {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setHeader(ACCEPT, APP_JSON);
            httpPost.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APP_JSON);
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(request, CHARSET);
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            CloseableHttpResponse response = closeableHttpClient.execute(httpPost);
            logger.info("Execution");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

My setPayment method is called max 3 times when execution is not successful. Sometimes after the first execution my method hangs with no response.
Any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 12):

I suggest you to do the following:

1) set timeout in a constructor:

```
public MyService() {
        int timeout = 180;      
        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(timeout * 1000)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout * 1000)
                .setSocketTimeout(timeout * 1000).build();
        closeableHttpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
    }
```

2) use try-with-resources to manage CloseableHttpResponse

```
    public String setPayment() {
    ...

                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setHeader(ACCEPT, APP_JSON);
                httpPost.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APP_JSON);
                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(request, CHARSET);
                httpPost.setEntity(entity);
try (CloseableHttpResponse response = closeableHttpClient.execute(httpPost)){                
                logger.info("Execution");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Error");
            }
        }
```